# 401 Unauthorized when calling Azure service via APIM

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management

I have a web service in Azure that must not be called via its `azurewebsites.net` endpoint, but only through our company's endpoint, `api.ourcompany.net` (not the real domain name).

I have protected the web service by whitelisting the Azure APIM's IP address in the web.config, like this (actual IP not shown):

```
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="Unauthorized">
    <!--This is for api.ourcompany.net -->
    <add allowed="true" ipAddress=“aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd” subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>
  </ipSecurity>
```

This works fine.

The service is called by an iPad app. The app must provide a `Bearer` token in the `Authorization` header. The token is an OAuth / JWT token obtained by user signing in to our company's sign in page within the app.

This works fine sometimes, and produces a 401 Unauthorized at other times. I am certain the token is valid in all cases and that the app is sending it properly.

As near as I can tell from troubleshooting, the token works when the user is connected to a company WiFi network or using a mobile device with LTE. It fails when user is connected to another WiFi network. It also seems to behave erratically when switching networks

I turned off whitelisting and the problem seems to have gone away.

My question is, how can I whitelist or otherwise protect my service, while using `Bearer` tokens?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out we have two APIM instances, and I only whitelisted one of them. The list I had was copied from a project deployed 2 years ago, and another APIM instance was added last year. Amazing how such a small thing can be so hard to troubleshoot.